# Seperate string and integer from array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I want to seperate the values of array by string and integer to make it more readable.

**Example**:

```
$array = [1,2,3,"string"];
```

**Return** would be like this:

```
'int' => [
    1,
    2,
    3
]
'string' => [
    "string"
]
```

Comment: What do you mean by *to make it more readable*?

Comment: I want to get the value of array if it is int or string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using [`is_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) and [`is_string`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php):

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if(is_int($value)) {
        $result['int'][] = $value;  
    }
    else if(is_string($value)) {
        $result['string'][] = $value;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/KZgg4)